# Critical region for difference in proportions

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

A new virus breaks out on a cruise ship. I want to test the hypothesis that males and females are equally likely to contract the virus.

I am going to test 100 men and 100 women. Presumably if I find 87 women infected and 89 men I cannot safely reject the null. If on the other hand I find 11 men are affected and 20 women this would seem a reasonable basis on which to reject the null.

So before running the test I want to define a rejection region. The rejection region is to be defined so that the probability of rejecting the null given that it is true is *at most* 5%. Since this is a composite null – the probability of getting the disease can range from 0 to 1 – this condition must hold for each and every member of the null.

How do I construct such a region?

Comment: I'm confident you can find great answers among the thousand or so posts dealing with [tests of proportions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+proportions).

Comment: I reviewed the 20 'most relevant' proportions posts and don't find this question answered so I am less confident. As a starting point I am trying to invert the chi-squared test even though this apparently only works asymtotically and not for small cell sizes. (My understanding is that Fisher's exact test is not applicable here as only one marginal is fixed.)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Controversies) the conditioning on the marginals does not matter. A search here on [test difference two proportions exact](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+difference+two+proportions+exact) turns up all kinds of variations of your question. Like you, though, I cannot find any *answers* that address this particular issue of how one goes about achieving a bound on the false positive rate: most answers appeal either implicitly or explicitly to asymptotic distributions.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper-Pearson_interval) and consider the phrase there "never has less than the nominal coverage for any population proportion" and what that would imply if you used it as the basis of a test. That may lead you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the chi-squared test seemed to work. This boils to down to the following. If *m* males are infected the null hypothesis should be rejected at the 5% level if the number females *f* infected is not within the range given by the roots of this quadratic:
$$(200+r) f^2 + (2 r m - 400 m- 200 r) f + [(200+r)m^2 - 200rm] = 0$$
Here r = 3.7 (which seemed to give a slightly tighter result than 3.84 – the 95th percentile of the chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom). I am happy enough with this answer.